# laravel 4-call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, html, symfony, laravel

I am trying to insert some data in database. I have created form with all fields and controller. 
CarController.php

```
public function create() {
        // load the create form (app/views/pages/create.blade.php)
        return View::make('pages.create');
    }

    public function store() {

            // store
            $data = new Car;
            $data->id = Input::get('id');
            $data->save();

            // redirect
            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created data!');
            return Redirect::to('pages/cars');

    }
```

routes.php

```
Route::resource('cars', 'CarController');
Route::post('desc', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
Route::post('create', array('uses' => 'CarController@create'));
Route::post('store', array('store' => 'CarController@store'));
```

create.blade.php

```
 {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'store', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('id', 'Vehicle ID',array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                {{ Form::text('id', Input::old('textId'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Vehicle ID')) }}
                </div>
            </div>             
            {{ Form::submit('Create the Car!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
        </div>
```

The problem is that it shows the following error:
**expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given**
I dont know what I have done wrong because I am new at laravel

Comment: just edited my question because this is the error shown now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a resource controller and that's why you only need one route declaretion for this, like:

```
Route::resource('cars', 'CarController');
```

You have also declared following routes:

```
Route::post('desc', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
Route::post('create', array('uses' => 'CarController@create'));
Route::post('store', array('store' => 'CarController@store'));
```

Actually you don't need these route declarations, only use first route and this will create routes for your resource controller. For example, your routes would look like these:

```
Method |   Url         | Action | Route Name
--------------------------------------------
GET    | /cars/create  | create | cars.create // domain.com/cars/create using GET
POST   | /cars         | store  | cars.store  // domain.com/cars using POST
```

There are more, you should check the [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers). In this case, you have two methods in your controller and if you use a `url` like `yourdomain.com/cars/create` using `GET` method (if you navigate from browser's address bar) then it'll invoke `create` method and if you submit a `form` using `POST` method to `yourdomain.com/cars` then it'll invoke the `store` method and all your form fields will be available in the `$_POST` array and you can use `Input::get('id')` to get `id` field's value. Check the socumentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

change this line in the route.php file

```
Route::post('store', array('store' => 'CarController@store'));
```

to

```
Route::post('uses', array('uses' => 'CarController@store'));
```

'uses' specify which function to call when you access the route